# How to speed up the conversion of data using SessionDataSetWrapper to map format?

Tags: time-series, apache-iotdb, iotdb

After reading the data in Apache IoTDB, I tried to traverse the data using SessionDataSetWrapper to "map" fromat. It takes about 4 seconds to transfer 30,000 time series data. Please tell me is there any way to optimize this conversion? Or is there a faster way to read the data in SessionDataSetWrapper?

No description on the official website